# Award, Scholarship, and Grant on educational financial sponsorship

Tags: funding

My Master's fee is sponsored (funding) by the Company where I am working currently. But, the university does not have any sponsorship scheme for my faculty. So, My company provides my fees as a financial sponsorship and I pay it as a regular fee to the university.
Now, I would like to add this sponsorship to the Research gate.
In the research gate there is a field for such cases.

> Grants, awards, and scholarships

```
Which field satisfies my sponsorship scheme among Grants, Awards, Scholarship?
```

Info : Discussions like in [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/difference-between-grants-and-awards) have no accepted answer on the given question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a scholarship (they're awarded by universities), you have a grant or an award, I'm unsure of the precise distinction, I suspect grant is more appropriate, since award suggests competition

Comment: I agree with @user2768. can I accept this answer?